# C# message box, deserialize JSON respon from HTTP POST request

Tags: c#

Can you please elaborate on how to use the JSON response from a HTTP `POST` request in a message box?

I just want 2 values from the JSON to show in my message box or even better if the display can be in table / datagrid.

I want to make it like this in the messagebox:

```
Brad  :  100
Maria :  50
Dina  :  25
```

or

```
| Brad  |  100  |
| Maria |   50  |
| Dina  |   25  |
```

Here's the JSON I get back from the HTTP `POST` request:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "Name": "Brad",
      "Amount": "100"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Maria",
      "Amount": "50"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dina",
      "Amount": "25"
    }
  ],
  "response": 200
}
```

And here's my C# code:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();

            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StreamReader>(responseContent);
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

            string nameValue = (string)json["Name"];
            string amountValue = (string)json["Amount"];

            MessageBox.Show(nameValue + " : " + amountValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried anything I found on Stackoverflow / Google but still can't find it working on mine.

Thank you so much guys for your time.

Comment: The message box is irrelevant. It will just display whatever `string` you pass to it. Your actual issue is to parse the JSON and then format the data in a `string` the way you want. As with any programming problem, the first step is to think about the logic involved. The code you have tries to get one `Name` value and one `Amount` value. How does that correspond to any logic that would apply to reading data that has a `values` element and then multiple couplets of `Name` and `Value` within that? If you can't describe the logic you need to implement, you shouldn't even be thinking about code.

Comment: Deserializing to a StreamReader (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StreamReader>()`) doesn't make any sense. You should be deserializing to an object. How familiar are you with using JSON.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two different methods of parsing the JSON using the JSON.Net library, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and `JObject.Parse`. Don't use both at the same time.

Option 1 - Fixing your `JObject.Parse` code.

After you parse the JSON into an object (`JObject.Parse` into `json`), you need to drill into the `values` property. For each object in that array, you can get the Name and Amount properties.

```
var responseContent = "{\"values\":[{\"Name\":\"Brad\",\"Amount\":\"100\"},{\"Name\":\"Maria\",\"Amount\":\"50\"},{\"Name\":\"Dina\",\"Amount\":\"25\"}],\"response\":200}";

JObject json = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
foreach (JObject value in json["values"])
{
    // make sure to index "value" not "json", as we want to access
    // each object in the values array, not the root of the JSON object.
    string name = value["Name"].Value<string>();
    string amount = value["Amount"].Value<string>();
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} : {amount}");
}
```

If you use Nullable Reference Types (and you should), you're going to have a crazy amount of warnings, so take care.

Option 2 - Using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` correctly.

To use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, you need to make your own type that correctly models the data you will be receiving. Use that type as the generic argument.

```
public class MyResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public int Response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("values")]
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(responseContent);
foreach(var value in data.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value.Name} : {value.Amount}");
}
```

I encurage you to use more descriptive class names than the ones I've shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize means to parse json to an instance of object(actually a model class) including same structures(properties).
so the method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(stream)` should be a model class of T